# GUI when call back

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have developed GUI interface in matlab. When I press a button, other buttons are not working anymore.
For example, I have run a function and if I wanted to open a file, the open file button is not working anymore and gives me following error :
when I run pushbutton16_Callback, pushbutton15_Callback is not work anymore. why ?

```
Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled2('pushbutton15_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback


function pushbutton15_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton15 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.*'},'Picture Selector');
fulpathname=strcat(pathname,filename);
set(handles.axes4,'Visible','On');
axes(handles.axes4)
imshow(fulpathname);
handles.pic=fulpathname;
info = imfinfo(fulpathname);
handles.format=info.Format;
guidata(hObject,handles);

function pushbutton16_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton16 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%pathname='C:\Users\Dr Syed Abdul Rahman\Desktop\innovation final\video detail\';
string1 = get(handles.edit1,'UserData');
%cd ..;
fName=strcat(cd,'\Video Detail\Video Detail',string1);
%    fName=strcat(cd,'\Video Detail',(string1));
try
 fid = fopen(fName);
sizS = 10000;
lineCt = 1;
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
s{lineCt} = tline;
lineCt = lineCt + 1;
%# grow s if necessary
if lineCt > sizS
   s = [s;cell(10000,1)];
   sizS = sizS + 10000;
end
tline = fgetl(fid);
end
%# remove empty entries in s
s(lineCt:end) = [];
set(handles.text4,'Visible','On');
set(handles.edit1,'Visible','On','String',s{1})
set(handles.edit2,'Visible','On','String',s{2})
set(handles.edit3,'Visible','On','String',s{3})
set(handles.edit4,'Visible','On','String',s{4})
set(handles.edit5,'Visible','On','String',s{5})
set(handles.edit6,'Visible','On','String',s{6})
set(handles.edit7,'Visible','On','String',s{7})
set(handles.axes4,'Visible','On');
%cd 'C:\Users\Dr Syed Abdul Rahman\Desktop\innovation final\Images';
cd './Images';
%str=strcat(string1);

A = imread('25');
axes(handles.axes4)
imshow(A);
%imshow('./video detail/1.jpg');
catch err
set(handles.text3,'Visible','On','String','File is not exist !') 
end
```

Comment: You need to post the code of your GUI, at least the callback function to that push button

Comment: If you are not sure whether the loop keeps running infinitely, consider printing the iteration number every 1000 times or so.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the problem:

```
sizS = 10000;
lineCt = 1;
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
  s{lineCt} = tline;
  lineCt = lineCt + 1;
  %# grow s if necessary
  if lineCt > sizS
     s = [s;cell(10000,1)];
     sizS = sizS + 10000;
  end
  tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

This code is very strange.  The while loop triggered me as it is a prime suspect in code getting stuck.

Then I saw your code does not make much sense. You first do `fgetl(fid)` 10000 times, then you do `sizS = sizS + 10000` and then you perhaps repeat this?

Regardless of the contents of your while loop, I dare guess that the stopping condition `ischar(tline)` is simply never met.

Comment: Dear Dennis thanks for interest. However, my question is I need my GUI run repetitively not for one times. I mean if I push a button, then other buttons are not work any more.

Comment: @AliBodaghi When you try to run the code in button 16, it will likely never end. As long as matlab is running one piece of code you will not be able to start another. Perhaps try simplyfing the code till a point where it does something trivial, but still allows you to push other buttons. Then you can expand from there and confirm the source of the problem.

Comment: Suppose that I develop a gui with 2 buttons A and B. when I push a button A, then other button B is not work anymore. Then, I must re-run the gui again for button B for working.

Comment: Dear @Dennis I have change the code with s{1} = fgetl(fid);
  s{2} = fgetl(fid);
 s{3} = fgetl(fid);
 s{4} = fgetl(fid);
 s{5} = fgetl(fid);
 s{6} = fgetl(fid);
 s{7} = fgetl(fid); But still I can not repeat my GUI due to following error. Undefined function 'untitled2' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled2('pushbutton8_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback